# Deleting cookies with WKHTTPCookieStore

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, webkit

I'm using the new `WKHTTPCookieStore` class in order to inject and delete cookies from `WKWebViews` in an app.

All of the `WKWebViews` share a common `WKWebViewConfiguration` so that they can share a common cookie store.

Injecting cookies works fine using the `add()` method, and each of the web views can see the new cookies and send them with their requests. Deleting cookies seems to be a problem - the web views all still see the supposedly deleted cookie, and continue to send it with each request:

```
let cookieStore = self.webkitConfiguration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore
cookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
    for cookie:HTTPCookie in cookies {
        if cookie.name == "CookieIWantToDelete" {
            cookieStore.delete(cookie, completionHandler: {
                self.webView.reload() //Deleted cookie is still sent with this request
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I can work around it by trashing all of the cookies in the `WKWebsiteDataStore`, but it seems a bit overkill.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear WKWebView cache before reloading by using `URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()`, for exampe, or use `self.webView.reloadFromOrigin()` to load fresh data.